# How to disable debug build in header-only library in port file in vcpkg?

Tags: vcpkg

I want to port one my library to Microsoft's vcpkg. This library is header-only. I created `portfile.cmake`, everything is fine. But `vcpkg install <mylibname>` builds release and debug. I have to say, that this build process is for internal for library generator of C++ code. So I want to have build only in release mode. How can I make it?

This was the first question. And from it the second one is coming. This generator places in `bin` folder and I have an error like

```
There should be no bin\ directory in a static build...
```

How can I enable to have `bin` directory with generator for header-only library in vcpkg?

I opened an issue in vcpkg's repository [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/17658)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to guys from vcpkg team. They answered on my questions.

To disable debug build in port file is needed to be added:

```
set(VCPKG_BUILD_TYPE release)
```

And there should not be `bin` directory, but in my case `tools/${PORT}` with executable should be. And `vcpkg_copy_tools()` is exactly for it.